# attach file send to email laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Homecontroller

```
public function contactsform()
   {
       $siteemail = 'adm.alisher@gmail.com';     $input = request()->all();

        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (request()->file('file') == null) 
        {
            $file = "";
        }else
        {
           $file = request()->file('file')->store('public/uploads');
        }
        if(!empty(request('file')))
        {
            $input['file'] = $file;
        }
        // dd($input['file']);
        \Mail::to($siteemail)
        ->send(new Contact($input));
        // return response()->json(['msg' => request('name')]);
        return view('welcome');
    }
```

App\Mail\Sendfile

```
public function build()
   {
 // return $this->view('view.name')->attach('/path/to/file');if(array_key_exists('file', $this->input) && strlen($this->input['file']) > 1)
        {
            Storage::setVisibility($this->input['file'], 'public');

            return $this->subject('Поваренок | Онлайн форма')
                    ->from('sitename@example.com')
                    ->view('emails.contact')
                    ->attach(env('APP_URL').Storage::url($this->input['file']));
        }
        else {
            return $this->subject('Поваренок | Онлайн форма')
                    ->from('sitename@example.com')
                    ->view('emails.contact');
        }
    }
```

but I want to send file email. Sorry guys. Please help me
front

```
<form action="/contactsform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
            <div class="order_form flex">
                <div class="flex input_block">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="order_input" placeholder="Имя*" required="">
                <input type="text" class="order_input" id="phone2" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон*" maxlength="20" required="">
                <input type="text" class="order_input" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="20" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form_send">
                    <textarea placeholder="Задайте вопрос" name="text"></textarea>
                    <div class="flex add_block">
                        <div class="add add_file"><input type="file" value="Прикрепить файл" name="file"></div>
                        <div class="add add_txt"><span>Вы можете прикрепить файл заявке до 10 мб</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_send_btn"><button type="submit" class="sub">Оставить заявку</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: can you add code for Contact class? What it does? Does it formats and prepares message to be sent via Mail?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your file path.

You are attaching the path of your file as URL which not correct

attachments takes the absolute path to file.

```
return $this->subject('Поваренок | Онлайн форма')
                ->from('sitename@example.com')
                ->view('emails.contact')
                ->attach(Storage::path($this->input['file']));
```

For more information please have a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#attachments